# Guessing game does not stop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
level = input("Easy gets 10 attempt Hard getse 5 attempt choose a level --> ").lower()
number = random.choice(range(101))
attempt = 0
if level == "easy":
    attempt = 10
else:
    attempt = 5

def check_number(guess,num):
    if guess == num:
        return "Correct You Won :)"
        win = True

    elif guess > num:
        return "Too high :("
    elif guess < num:
        return "Too low :("
win = False
while attempt > 0 and win == False:
    guess = int(input("Guess the number "))
    print(check_number(guess,number))
    attempt -= 1
    print(f"You have {attempt} attempt left")

if win == True:
    print(f"GOOD JOB YOU HAVE {attempt} LEFT")
else:
    print("NEXT TİME :(")
```

It does not stop when you guess the number, still asks for new guess.
I couldn't find the problem. I just started learning python.

Comment: The `win` in your function is a local variable that is not connected to the `win` global variable.  Of course, it wouldn't matter, because you don't set `win` to True until after you return.  I'll post a better design below.

Comment: Don't use `globals`, they may cause errors in updating the variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This avoids using a global variable at all:

```
import random
level = input("Easy gets 10 attempt Hard getse 5 attempt choose a level --> ").lower()
number = random.choice(range(101))
attempt = 0
if level == "easy":
    attempt = 10
else:
    attempt = 5

def check_number(guess,num):
    if guess > num:
        return False, "Too high :("
    elif guess < num:
        return False, "Too low :("
    return True, "Correct You Won :)"

win = False
while attempt > 0 and not win:
    guess = int(input("Guess the number "))
    win, msg = check_number(guess,number)
    print(msg)
    if not win:
        attempt -= 1
        print(f"You have {attempt} attempt left")

if win:
    print(f"GOOD JOB YOU HAVE {attempt} LEFT")
else:
    print("NEXT TİME :(")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two problems:

1. `win` assigned after return and it won't run
2. `win` is inside a function and its like you define a new variable `win` inside the function and can't access it from outside

so you might want to do sth like this:

```
import random
level = input("Easy gets 10 attempt Hard getse 5 attempt choose a level --> ").lower()
number = random.choice(range(101))
attempt = 0
if level == "easy":
    attempt = 10
else:
    attempt = 5

def check_number(guess,num):
    if guess == num:
        return 0
    elif guess > num:
        return 1
    elif guess < num:
        return -1
win = False
while attempt > 0 and win == False:
    guess = int(input("Guess the number "))
    state = check_number(guess,number)
    if(state==0):
        win = True
        print("won")
    elif(state==1):
        print("is high")
    elif(state==-1):
        print("is low")
    attempt -= 1
    print(f"You have {attempt} attempt left")

if win == True:
    print(f"GOOD JOB YOU HAVE {attempt} LEFT")
else:
    print("NEXT TİME :(")
```